# Greedy approach to find maximum product $P = (A-k_{1})*(B-k_{2}).$

Tags: calculus, binary

Suppose you are given two integers $A$ and $B$; $A \leq B$. I have to calculate the maximum possible value of the expression $P = (A-k_{1})*(B-k_{2}).$ Here $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ both are variables but its not guaranteed that $k_{1}$ or $k_{2}$ = $0$. Is there any greedy approach to choose $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ so that it maximises $P$ ?

Comment: I want to know the intervals where the product is maximum for minimum value of $k_{1}+k_{2}$

Comment: I guess you need to be more specific about the restrictions on $k_1,k_2$. The above comment doesn't make sense, you cannot usually optimize two things at the same time ("product maximum, $k_1+k_2$ minimum"). For starters, which values can $k_1,k_2$ take at all: integers or reals, must they be positive or can they be negative,etc? A "greedy" strategy usually indicates that there are restrictions, what are they.

Comment: @Ingix sorry for that, I think I am a little confused. I will close this question for now and rethink about what I actually want. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that k1 and k2 can not be always 0, I want to point out that P is a strictly decreasing function as we increase k1 and k2. If A < B then I suggest that you try to keep A as large as possible and try to decrease B.

Comment: It will be better if you can explain the reason too.